# Write a function that takes in a positive int value n and returns the longest increasing run of digits - Overflow Error

Tags: python-3.x

Write the function longestIncreasingRun that takes in a positive int value n and returns the longest increasing run of digits. For example

longestIncreasingRun(1232) would return 123 and longestIncreasingRun(27648923679) returns 23679. If there is a tie in run length, the larger of the two runs should be returned. So longestIncreasingRun(123345) would return 345.

I got an overflow error when I ran the program.I wonder how to let the program to give correct output

```
def longestDigitRunSequence(n):
    if n<0:
        n-=n
    count=1
    prev=n%10
    num=n%10
    n=n/10
    max=0
    while n:
        digit=n%10
        if digit>=prev:
            if count>max:
                longest=num
                max=count
            elif count==max:
                if num>longest:
                    longest=num
            count=1
            prev=digit
            num=digit
        else:
            num=digit*10**count+num
            prev=digit
            count+=1
        n=n/10
    if count>max:
        longest=num
        max=count
    elif count==max:
        if num>longest:
            longest=num
    return longest
def test():
    print("Testing longestDigitRunSequence()",end="")
    assert(longestDigitRunSequence(1232) == 123)
    assert(longestDigitRunSequence(27648923679) == 23679)
    assert(longestDigitRunSequence(123345) == 345)
    print("Passed")
test()
```

Comment: can you please explain why `longestIncreasingRun(123345) would return 345.`? Comparing with other examples you have stated, I think, it should return `12345`.

Comment: because the next digit should be larger than the previous digit, and also need to be consecutive， 12345 skip the digit "3" in 123345 but it cannot skip